# How to increase float build number by using script

Tags: xcode, bash, version, cfbundleidentifier, build-numbers

Hello guys i have tried following ways but none of them helped me to increase it without having any error on command line.

My current build number is 1.4.0 , i wanna get 1.5.0..

## get bundle version and build version values from info.plist file

```
BUNDLE_VERSION=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print:CFBundleShortVersionString" <my plist path>)
BUILD_NUMBER=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :CFBundleShortVersionString" <my plist path>)
```

## increase build number by one

```
#BUILD_NUMBER=`echo $BUILD_NUMBER +1|bc` //have tried this one first but didnt work
BUILD_NUMBER=$((BUILD_NUMBER+=1)) //that one also didnt help
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BUILD_NUMBER=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :CFBundleVersion" <my plist path>)
echo $BUILD_NUMBER
```

## increase build number by one

```
NEWSUBVERSION=`echo $BUILD_NUMBER | awk -F "." '{print $3}'`
NEWSUBVERSION=$(($NEWSUBVERSION + 1))
NEWVERSIONSTRING=`echo $BUILD_NUMBER | awk -F "." '{print $1 "." $2 ".'$NEWSUBVERSION'" }'`
echo $NEWVERSIONSTRING
```

## update build number in info plist in the main project

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion ${NEWVERSIONSTRING}" <my plist path>
```